# Dynamic JPA count query not responding

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have created in a Spring Boot project a dynamic function that builds dynamic JPA queries with pagination. The main and count query are built correctly at runtime, I have even tested them directly in DB and they work fine. The problem is when the count statement is executing, the query never respond and does not show error messages. The count query built at runtime takes 4565ms in SQLDeveloper tool.

I share a code snippet and an image of where the logs are stopped...

```
    Page<T> resultPage;        
 ....
    //create main JPA query 
    Query mainQuery = coreEntityManager.createQuery(queryBuilder.toString(), resultClass);
    //create count JPA query
    Query countQuery = coreEntityManager.createQuery(countQueryBuilder);

    //set pageable params
    int pageNumber = pageable.getPageNumber();
    int pageSize = pageable.getPageSize();
    //set first result cursor in main query
    mainQuery.setFirstResult((pageNumber) * pageSize);
    //set max result values in main query
    mainQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);

    //set parameters in queries
    for (String key : parameterMap.keySet()) {
        //main query
        mainQuery.setParameter(key, parameterMap.get(key));
        //count query
        countQuery.setParameter(key, parameterMap.get(key));
    }

    //run main query
    List<T> fooList = mainQuery.getResultList();
    //check result
    if (fooList == null || fooList.size() == 0) {
        //if empty return 
        resultPage = new CustomPage<T>(new ArrayList<T>());
    } else {
        //if contains values return pageable values
        Long size= (Long) countQuery.getSingleResult();
        log.debug("Size result query: {}",size);
        resultPage = new CustomPage<T>(fooList, pageable, size);
    }

    return resultPage;
```

[image]

Comment: are the select query and the count query similar? do you notice any unnecessary cross joins? do you have good indexes?

Comment: The main and count query are similar, the difference is what they get but the conditions are the same. Conditions have indexed. The execution time directly in DB is less than 5s. Debugging I noticed that the delay occurs in the ojdbc6 drive library, but nothing conclusive...

Comment: do the two queries work separately?

Comment: Yes, first run the main paged query and then if it returns values ​​then run the count query with the same 'where' conditions.